# Is it possible to use ContentProvider and direct data access to Database in Android?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider, sqliteopenhelper

I have application that uses **direct** data access to it's Database. I have nothing to expose outside of it for other applications. As CommonsWare says somewhere on SO, "if you have nothing to expose - don't use ContentProvider". Now, I want to add widget to display a couple of strings from one of the tables, storing in Database. Should I refactor the **direct access** code to the **ContentProvider** pattern? Is there a way to use direct access to Database from widget? Is there a way to have both ContentProvider and direct access to database in one application?

Comment: I have opened a similar question but in my case the widget application is a separate application. So the proposed answer is not applicable.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403569/is-it-possible-to-use-contentprovider-and-direct-data-access-to-database-in-andr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I want to add widget to display a couple of strings from one of the tables, storing in Database.

I am going to assume that by "widget" you really mean "app widget".

> Should I refactor the direct access code to the ContentProvider pattern?

You do not have to do this just because you are writing an app widget.

> Is there a way to use direct access to Database from widget?

Sure, using the same mechanisms you are using anywhere else in your app.

> Is there a way to have both ContentProvider and direct access to database in one application?

Yes, though you have to be a bit careful to make sure that you are using the same `SQLiteDatabase` object in both cases, so you do not run into threading issues.