# Is it possible to use ContentProvider and direct data access to Database in Android? (multiple application case)

Tags: android, database, concurrency, android-contentprovider

I have a similar question as here: [Is it possible to use ContentProvider and direct data access to Database in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772174/is-it-possible-to-use-contentprovider-and-direct-data-access-to-database-in-andr) but in my case I want the widget application to be a separate application.

So I have a first Android application that is using a sqlite database using standard SQLiteOpenHelper. this helper is a singleton that is created in my Application onCreate. Works good.

Now I want to make a second application -so a widget application- that needs to access the database as well. So I would like to use a ContentProvider for that.

1) is it safe to do such way or do I have to refactor the main application to use only ContentProvider (clearly would be a showstopper for me!!)

2) if it is ok, how should I design the contentProvider? I guess I will have to reuse my singleton SQLiteOpenHelper and eventually create it in contentProvider.onCreate?

Comment: It is preferable to have both elements use the same mecanism, namely the contentprovider

Comment: @njzk2 : "preferable"? so you mean using different mecanisms is possible?? ;-)
Indeed moving existing code to contentprovider will be a nightmare.

Comment: moving to a content provider should be very different. after all, the contentprovider gives your CRUD, just like your database classes probably does. It is, however possible to access a database with several methods at the same time, though i don't see why someone would want to do that

Comment: thanks njzk2. Do you know if there is any impact expected on performance? I don't care for DB access from the widget, but INSERT/QUERY performance from my main application are very important as I have big tables (already optimized with transaction)

Comment: not that i know of. contentprovider provide a mechanism for batches, too

Comment: ok thanks, I will look at this solution, but will probably give a try with mixed may first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also trying to use a `ContentProvider` and a singleton db object. This appears to be a valid approach.

Quoting from: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/20d8cbf7bf88f6d9

> "Only open the database once.  If you are not using a content
>   provider, implement a singleton that takes care of opening the
>   database once for all code in your app.
>
> "And let me be clear -- there is NOTHING wrong with the content
>   provider never closing the database.  Nothing.  That is NO reason to
>   avoid using a content provider.  In fact it is a very good design
>   approach, and if you aren't using a content provider but directly
>   accessing, I would recommend using the exact same approach for the
>   singleton implementation.
>
> "If you want to have a content provider *AND* also elsewhere do direct
>   access to the database, then implement your content provider on top of
>   the singleton that owns the database.
>
> --  Dianne Hackborn Android framework engineer hack...@android.com